# Call inherited method

Tags: c++, templates

I have base class called "Packet" with following method :

```
    template <typename T>
    void write()
    {
        //DoSomething
        writeHandler<T>();
    }
```

and a child class called PacketA who implement a template spezialisation method for each **handler**

In PacketA i want writte a method called B() like following

```
public function B() { write<MySpezialisation>(); }
```

I presume it's will call Packet::write with
my spezialisation writeHandler

if i had my base class
`Packet::write<MySpecialisation>();}`
it's not calling my template spezialisation method.

What is wrong ?

```
#ifndef CLIENTIPPACKET_H
#define CLIENTIPPACKET_H

/*INCLUDES SKIPPED*/
class PacketA : public Packet
{

public:

    struct MySpecialization
    {
    };

    PacketA() : Packet() {}

private:
    template<typename T> void writeHandler();

public:
    void write() { Packet::writeHandler<MySpezialisation>(); }

};

template<>
void PacketA::writeHandler<PacketA::MySpecialization>()
{
   //DOSOMETHING
}

#endif
```

Comment: Would you post PacketA class ?

Comment: Your update to a question example does not follow the main `Packet` code shown: there is no `Packet::writeHandler()`.

Comment: Still, this line in `PacketA` is very strange: `void write() { Packet::writeHandler<MySpezialisation>(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you expect your `Packet` understand that `writeHandler()` should come from `PacketA`? `writeHandler()` is not virtual (and can not be, as it is templated), so `Packet` will always use its own version.

I can suggest rewriting it to

```
template <typename T, typename P>
void write(T data, P& packet) 
{
    m_data.clear();
    getStream()->atStart();
    packet.writeHandler<T>(data);
    getStream()->atStart();
}
```

and in `PacketA`

```
public function B() { write<MySpezialisation>(data, *this); }
```

(have you forgot `data` in your code in quetion?)

However, a better approach can exist depending on your particular design needs.

Comment: Uhhmm, i will explain my design :

I have a Packet base class with some data.
When my server send my packet i want to identify him (i have opcode) 
but also is payload (Payload struct for each packet)

For each packet, i have specific action for read, write or prepare the packet.

Each time i read, write or prepare i need to execute specific action like clear , atStart but i don't want rewrite this lines each time i make a new subPacket class.

Comment: Write the explanation in your question and not in the comment section please.

Comment: @Totomakers, you might want to add this to the main question. Or better post a new question, because it is a different problem from your original "why it's not calling my template spezialisation method"

Comment: @rbaleksandar, you did not mention (@) Totomakers in your comment, so he might have not seen it ---  I doubt that the author of _question_ gets notified of all comments to all answers.

Comment: I will post a new aquestion ;)